# How to determine if app has been re-opened for Cordova Apps?

Tags: android, ios, cordova

I know there are a few techniques to see if IOS and Android apps are opened again (so if a user minimizes the app and then reopens it to the same state), but I am not sure how to do this in Cordova. Has anyone had success with this?

My only thoughts on how to solve this is to either just doing a check on the data that I am concerned with every x-seconds to see if there are changes in the background, but that seems bad practice with data on mobile, even though they should be small.

The other thought was to try writing a new plugin that can use the native techniques, but have not reached the point where that seems like a good fit either.

Hoping someone has a better idea or can at least tell me that one of these thoughts is not completely crazy.

Comment: Have you tried http://stackoverflow.com/a/15411538/2708650 ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looking at:

http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/cordova_events_events.md.html#resume

I see:

```
document.addEventListener("resume", yourCallbackFunction, false);
```

Which says:

> The resume event fires when the native platform pulls the application
>   out from the background.
>
> Applications typically should use document.addEventListener to attach
>   an event listener once the deviceready event fires.

Comment: Seriously I must be tired... I could not find that all last night when I was looking. That should work beautifully. Thanks!

Comment: Haha it happens to us all.  Np